# Remove substring from the words in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, substring

I have the pandas data frame:

```
df:

id  des
1   POS Transfer atis mcdon uber
2   MKLI QC Montreal abelutixy
3   PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22
```

I want to add a new column "new" to the dataframe, where all the words in the `df.des` that has the substring `tis`, `ber` `uti` be removed

That is

df["new"]:

```
   POS Transfer mcdon
   MKLI QC Montreal
   PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22
```

How do I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
In [68]: ddf['new'] = ddf.des.str.replace(r'\w*(tis|ber|uti)\w* ?', '')

In [69]: ddf
Out[69]: 
                               des                             new
id                                                                
1     POS Transfer atis mcdon uber             POS Transfer mcdon 
2       MKLI QC Montreal abelutixy               MKLI QC Montreal 
3   PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22  PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22
```